# Golang shadowing variable

Tags: go

Why in this code the variable 'a' is shadowed? I define it in outer scope, then, in the inner scope I have to use the ':=' syntax to assign a new value to it (result from a function call), because I also need to have the 'err' variable, which is new. But this shadows 'a', and later, outside the block, the 'a' returns automatically to the initial value.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func work() {
    a := "outside"

    {
        a, err := foo()
        fmt.Printf("here: %v %v\n", a, err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("but here: %v \n", a)
}

func foo() (string, error) {
    return "inside", fmt.Errorf("WTF?")
}

func main() {
    work()
}
```

The result is:

```
here: inside WTF?
but here: outside
```

So this forces me to use a new variable in the inner block, e.g. 'b', and then assign 'b' to 'a', like this? This would be stupid, wouldn't it? I feel like I am missing something here. Please help.

```
func work() {
    a := "outside"

    {
        b, err := foo()
        a = b // I DON'T WANT THIS !!!
        fmt.Printf("here: %v %v\n", a, err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("but here: %v \n", a)
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using short-form variable declaration, which will redeclare the variables in the outer scope, and thus, shadowing them. You can simply declare the error variable, and use regular assignment

```
func work() {
    a := "outside"

    {
        var err error
        a, err = foo() // No shadowing
    }

    fmt.Printf("but here: %v \n", a)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a bit inconvenient, but I just assume it is the way that Go works. Thanks.

Comment: it feels strange at first but once you get used to it, you may like the explicit distinction between declaration and assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Shadowing occurs in Go when a variable declared in a nested scope has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope. In such cases, the variable in the inner scope **shadows** or hides the variable in the outer scope.

**Example:**

```golang
func main() {
    x := 10
    fmt.Println("Outer x:", x) // Outer x: 10

    {
        x := 20
        fmt.Println("Inner x:", x) // Inner x: 20
    }

    fmt.Println("Outer x:", x) // Outer x: 10
}
```